# C# MVC ViewModel One Posted Result Binds Whilst Others Are Null

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, post, model-view-controller

I have a number of awards in my view and within each award there is a corresponding list of qualifications. I have created a ViewModel to display each award and with a click of a button a modal should appear with its relevant qualifications which can be marked as completed/updated by the user. However on the Post of the data only my first Award will bind in my controller method.The rest will comeback as Null when I debug in VS. The data is appearing in my view as expected with each Award only showing its relevant qualifications. Thanks in advance for helping with this.

**ViewModel**

```
public class CandidateExtended
{
public CandidateExtended()
{
    this.Qualifications = new List<Qualification_Extended>();
}

public int AwardID { get; set; }
public int FrameworkID { get; set; }
public string ULN { get; set; }
public string Forename { get; set; }
public string Surname { get; set; }
public string TitleShort { get; set; }
public string TitleFull { get; set; }
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
public string Award { get; set; }
public int AwardLevel { get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }
public string Completion { get; set; }
public string SelectedRoute { get; set; }

public List<Qualification_Extended> Qualifications { get; set; }

public void addQualification(Qualification_Extended qualification)
{
    Qualifications.Add(qualification);
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var awardDetails = (from award in db.award
                        join candidate in db.candidate
                        on award.ULN equals candidate.ULN
                        join framework in db.framework
                        on award.QAN equals framework.QAN
                        where award.OrganisationIdentityID == organisationID
                        select new AwardDetails_Extended
                        {
                            AwardID = award.AwardID,
                            ULN = award.ULN,
                            AwardStatus = award.AwardStatus,
                            Forename = candidate.Forename,
                            Surname = candidate.Surname,
                            DOB = candidate.DOB,
                            FrameworkID = framework.FrameworkID,
                            TitleFull = framework.TitleFull,
                            TitleShort = framework.TitleShort, 
                            AwardLevel = framework.AwardLevel, 
                            Award = framework.Award,
                            Completion = framework.Completion
                        }).ToList();


    var qualificationDetails = (from candidateQualification in db.candidateQualification
                                join qualification in db.qualification
                                on candidateQualification.QualificationID equals qualification.QualificationID
                                select new Qualification_Extended
                                {
                                    ID = candidateQualification.ID,
                                    QualificationID = candidateQualification.QualificationID,
                                    ULN = candidateQualification.ULN,
                                    FrameworkID = candidateQualification.FrameworkID,
                                    Achieved = candidateQualification.Achieved,
                                    DateAchieved = candidateQualification.DateAchieved
                                }).ToList();


    List<CandidateExtended> candidateVM = new List<CandidateExtended>();

    foreach (var item in awardDetails)
    {
        CandidateExtended vm = new CandidateExtended();
        vm.AwardID = item.AwardID;
        vm.FrameworkID = item.FrameworkID;
        vm.ULN = item.ULN;
        vm.Forename = item.Forename;
        vm.Surname = item.Surname;
        vm.DOB = item.DOB;
        vm.TitleShort = item.TitleShort;
        vm.TitleFull = item.TitleFull;
        vm.Award = item.Award;
        vm.AwardLevel = item.AwardLevel;
        vm.Status = item.AwardStatus;
        vm.Completion = item.Completion;
        vm.SelectedRoute = item.SelectedRoute;

        foreach (var qualification in qualificationDetails)
        {
            if (qualification.ULN == item.ULN && qualification.FrameworkID == item.FrameworkID)
            {
                vm.addQualification(qualification);
            }
        }

        candidateVM.Add(vm);
    }

    return View(candidateVM);      
}
```

**View**

```
@model List<Apprenticeship_SingleAward.ViewModels.CandidateExtended>

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Single Award Apprenticeships";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Organisation.cshtml";
}


<div class="application-table table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped administration-table">
        <thead>
            <tr class="admin-table-heading">
                <th>ULN</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Award</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Qualifications</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Count(); j++)
        {
            var award = Model[j];

            <tr>
                <td>@award.ULN</td>
                <td>@award.Forename</td>
                <td>@award.Surname</td>
                <td>@award.TitleShort</td>
                <td>@award.Award</td>
                <td>@award.AwardLevel</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn qualificationbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@qualificationModal">@displayQualTotal<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil org-edit-icon"></i></button>

                    @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateAward", "Organisation", FormMethod.Post, new { id = award.AwardID}))
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(a => Model[j].AwardID)

                        <div id="@qualificationModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog organisationmodal">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                  <div class="modal-body">
                                      <h4 class="org-modal-subheading">@award.TitleShort</h4>
                                      <br />
                                      <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="row org-row-main">
                                                    <div class="col-md-7"><h4 class="org-type">Qualification</h4></div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-2"><h5 class="org-completed">Completed</h5></div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-3"><h5 class="org-date">Date</h5></div>
                                                </div>

                                                <hr class="org-hr"/>

                                                 @for (int i = 0; i < Model[j].Qualifications.Count(); i++)
                                                 {
                                                    <div class="row org-row">
                                                       <div class="col-md-7">
                                                           @Html.HiddenFor(a => Model[j].Qualifications[i].ID)
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                                           @Html.CheckBoxFor(a => Model[j].Qualifications[i].Achieved)
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-3"
                                                            >@Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model[j].Qualifications[i].DateAchieved, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
                                                        </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                 }
                                             </div>
                                       </div> 
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn ccea-signout" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn admin-button" style="margin-top: 0;">Save</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @{
                    var status = award.Status;
                    if (status == "In Progress")
                    {
                        <button class="btn progressbutton" style="margin: 0;">@status</button>
                    }
                    }
               </td>
            </tr>

        }

      </tbody>
  </table>
```

**UpdateAward**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateAward(List<CandidateExtended> Model)
{

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");

}
```

Comment: "However on the Post of the data only my first Award will bind in my controller" - Since you post one Award at a time I don't understand this statement.

Comment: Yes I post one award at a time. The first award displayed on the page will post fine and Bind when I test it. However afterwards when I try any of the other awards that are displayed, when posted they will not bind and are null in VS. @RyanSearle

Comment: Take a look at what is sent to your application. In Chrome open developer tools, under the network tab find your request and paste the results in your answer if you need to.

Comment: How does that UpdateAward method even work the first time? It looks to me like the call to post just sends an ID and not only that there is no [frombody] in the param of the API?

Comment: Having multiple forms in your view makes no sense at all - you can only post one at a time. And only the first will bind because ny default, the `DefaultModelBinder` required that collection indexers start a zero and be consecutive

Comment: Why are you generating multiple forms? - do you want to be able to editing multiple `CandidateExtended` instances (in which case, have just one form containing your nested loops), or do you want to edit only one `CandidateExtended` (in which case, you view should be displaying just a list of `CandidateExtended` with a link to edit each one

Comment: Yeah it was a requirement from the front end developer to have multiple forms in the same page. However due to the issues it has given I have talked him into going with a new view with a single form for each candidate. Thanks for your advice over the past few days.

Answer (score 1):

The way it is set up now (with `BeginForm` **inside** the `@for`, and a Submit button for every 'mini'-Form), every submit will do a Form Post containing exactly one item from the list.

If that is how you want it to work (edit one item at a time), then you may keep it. Do keep in mind however (add a comment?) that even though the Post Action method is *ready* to receive a List, there never will be multiple items in the List because each 'mini'-Form contains just one item.

If on the other hand you want to be able to save multiple items at once, then move the `BeginForm` **outside** the `@for`, and use just one Submit button at the end of the Form, e.g. just before the closing `}`.

Comment: Yeah that is how I want it to work.I want the user to Edit one at a time and then submit the 'mini-form' when they are happy with it. At the minute this is working for one of the awards shown to the user on the view; there are 6 awards. However if they wish to submit any other awards / 'mini-forms' it will return a null model. I have tested each of the awards and only one will bind when posted back. I deleted my data and re-entered it to make sure nothing there was influencing this but I get the same behavior again.

Comment: I did not realize you wanted single-item forms, otherwise I would not have proposed you make that change (to use a List). To make it work *with the List* will probably mean you need to add dummy-items with indexes into each form, so the indexes used in each form will always start at zero, upto the index of item that you are editing. The cleaner alternative is to stop using a List, which means going back to a non-indexed Model item inside each form, and to use Qualification_Extended in the Post Action Method.

Comment: Yeah it was a requirement from the front end developer to have multiple forms in the same page. However due to the issues it has given I have talked him into going with a new view with a single form for each candidate. Thanks for your advice over the past few days.